# Stripe didn't create invoices

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

According to stripe's dashboard (test mode), customer's next subscription invoice should have been created on April 28th at 5AM but it's April 29th today and the invoice has not been created yet and when I am trying to update the customer's subscription with stripe api for node js, I get the following error :

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: The subscription is currently invoicing and thus cannot be updated.
```

Then I tried to force to create an invoice but got the following error :

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: Nothing to invoice for customer
```

I have not Idea why stripe doesn't want to create this invoice and I don't know how I can force it to be created.

Any idea ?

Comment: the auto subscription of stripe is something not good at this moment, my team have faced it, I think move code of subscription to our backend and do one time charge will make everything easier. If you are on the solution of using auto subscription stripe, some of feature will not work with test card (somehow)

Comment: the invoice of next subscription will be get as upcoming invoice, try to pay those invoice

Answer (score 1):

When an invoice is created, Stripe will send an `invoice.created` event and wait for a successful webhook response to finalize and attempt to pay the invoice.

If the Stripe doesn't receive a successful webhook response, it will wait for 72 hours before finalizing the invoice. This is a long delay that you want to avoid.

You might want to check if your webhook endpoint and see if it's responding to `invoice.created` events quickly.